# 404 error from Servlet using Eclipse & Tomcat 6

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I've looked at all the other questions on this matter (and there is a LOT of them), and they all end up being a typo with the address, or a misconfigured servlet mapping, or similar. I've tried all of this stuff and I'm still coming back with a 404 error whenever I try to access a page from my servlet.

Here's the servlet code (basic hello world example taken from mkyong's site)

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 
}
```

And here's my servlet definition and mapping in the deployment descriptor

```
<servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/testservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here's the error I'm getting

```
HTTP Status 404 - /testserver/testservlet
type Status report
message /testserver/testservlet
description The requested resource (/testserver/testservlet) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.33
```

Anybody got any idea what might be causing this?

EDIT: I just tested the JSP and Servlet hello world given here

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/

and it worked fine, so I think the problem is with my servlet. Anybody got any ideas what might be wrong with it?

Comment: How are you accessing your servlet?

Comment: Accessing localhost:8080/testserver/testservlet

Comment: Is there any errors in log files in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/logs directory?

Comment: Wild guess.. Is Tomcat running. Check `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: localhost:8080 gives a 404 error as well, but the error is coming from Tomcat so it's definitely running. As far as I know, you can't access the welcome page when Tomcat is running through Eclipse, so this is normal.

Comment: can you access anything under /testserver/ path?

Comment: @Hardik: Think for a sec. If Tomcat didn't run, then the OP wouldn't have gotten a Tomcat-specific 404 error, but a browser-specific connection timeout error.

Comment: No, I can't access anything under the testserver path

Comment: Still haven't fixed this issue, going to put a bounty on it as soon as I can, if anyone has any other suggestions what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the war file. If you have a war file named 'testme.war', you have to access it like this.

localhost:8080/**testme/testservlet**

Comment: Eclipse isn't creating a war file when I build the project, maybe this is the source of the issue? (Tomcat has nothing to run?). I've already added the project onto my tomcat server in Eclipse, so I just assumed that would handle it all. What do I have to do to get it to create the war file and deploy it to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

According to your mapping, you should be accessing it through : `http://localhost:8080/testservlet`

Where does the "testserver" come from ? Do you have any reason to use it ?

Comment: That's the name of the server project in Eclipse